# How to properly mount new hdd, to free up the old one

Tags: ubuntu, mount, hard-disk

I installed a new hdd `/dev/sdb1`, and mounted to `/home/ubuntu/new1`, and moved some files there to free up the old hdd, but when I do `du -h` `new1` is still takes space in the old hdd, below are my `fstab` config and `du` output.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=93924d6f-e087-44e2-aabc-288c9a89d859 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdb1 /home/ubuntu/new1 ext3 defaults 0 2

[ubuntu@ubuntu:~]$df -Th
Filesystem                  Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ext4      6.5G  5.6G  597M  91% /
udev                        devtmpfs  494M  4.0K  494M   1% /dev
tmpfs                       tmpfs     201M  332K  201M   1% /run
none                        tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                        tmpfs     502M     0  502M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1                   ext3      7.9G  1.2G  6.4G  15% /home/ubuntu/new1
/dev/sda1                   ext2      228M   27M  190M  13% /boot
```

Comment: How did you move the files? If you did not use the commandline (`mv`) but Nautilus, make sure you empty your Trashcan before running `df`

Comment: I run Ubuntu server, and ran command `mv stuff new1` @Anthon

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say where it's gone wrong.  The best thing you can do is to track down the large files using the `du` utility.

This utility lists disk usage (hence it's name) but will need some coaxing to give useful results.

Run:

```
sudo du -axhd3 / | sort -rhk1 | head
```

to list the top 10 largest files/directories looking at a depth of 3 directories deep.  Change `head` to `less` to see the whole list and change the `3` in the `du` command to look at more or less than 3 deep.

You should be able to see where your 5.6G is used.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have root as a volume group and you have mounted sdb1 and move some files. I guess what you want is to *add the new hdd to that volume group* and you didn't do any of that. Check the next [link](http://linuxconfig.org/linux-lvm-logical-volume-manager)